# DKIM wrong selector / domain

Tags: configuration, dkim

We're having an hard time setting the DKIM record for our sender domain. I'll get into more details:

We have a valid key (check) for a sending subdomain (email.mydomain.com) with selector ESP1024
In the dns, the record appears to be set up properly (our registrar confirmed it) and DIG results confirms it as well.

nonetheless, whenever we send an email from that domain, the tests shows an error, finding no key for the signature:
selector: ESP (instead of ESP1024) Domain:mydomain.com (instead of email.mydomain.com).

Any idea why this could be happening?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What are you using to sign? OpenDKIM? Something else? Is whatever it is configured correctly?

Comment: I am awaiting our ESP to reply on this one. I cannot find any other reason for this failure, also considering that other domains we have, with the same exact DNS configuration, works perfectly fine.

Comment: Did your ESP tell you to use ESP1024 as the selector? Sounds almost like theyre setup to use ESP as the selector, and your bare domain in the signature, so maybe just change your DNS to match....

Comment: We have been given this new key by our ESP, as replacement to substitute old 512 keys. In the end, it ended up being an error on our ESP signing configuration, as you first suggested, that now have been sorted.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it is all sorted out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update on this one:

- we checked everything in the DNS record and performed checks on the key propagation.
- we checked the key and it was confirmed as valid and active.
- the error was in the ESP that made mistakes in the configuration of the signing of messages itself. If I happen to have more details that can be useful for others, I will update this answer.

Thanks,